# Code still runs after startActivity()

Tags: android, android-activity

My app lauches on a splash activity, if I don't have certain credentials in my database, it has to go a login page.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, Login.class);
startActivity(intent);
Log.d("debug", "code is still executing!!!");
```

**Problem**: after my startActivity(), it still runs all the code below.
("code is still executing" is printed in the console).

**Goal**: don't execute any code from splash activity, go to login activity.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's normal behaviour. `startActivity()` does not terminate current one nor instantly aborts/quits the code it is called from. It adds a new intent to the handler's queue for further processing, yet this intent won't be handled by the framework unless control is returned to the system event loop, which usually means unless your method ends executing.

If you really need to terminate current activity just call `finish()` in your method to tell the framework you done with this one. Note, again, that `finish()` does not terminates the current Activity instantly, so if you got code after `finish()` it will be executed. If that's not your intention, use i.e `return;` to return control to the framework just after `finish()` call.

Snippet from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()):

> **void finish ()**
>
> Call this when your activity is done and should be
> closed. The ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you
> via onActivityResult().

Comment: I added this.finish() after startActivity, all code still gets executed?

Comment: I refactored my code so I won't have to call finish anymore,
thanks a lot for pointing out that startActivity doesn't mean the rest of the code won't get executed!

Answer (score 3):

This is the normal behavior. The **startActivity()** is just a 'request' it doesn't to launch a new activity, the current one will remain executing the rest of the code until its 'death' then the onPause() followed by the onDestroy() is executed. You can read amore about the Activity life cycle here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Answer (score 1):

It's normal behavior in Android. `startActivity()` method does not terminate the current activity you are in. If you want your code should not execute further, add return and if you want to cancel your activity add finish().